# Calling get_post_custom outputs 38 on screen

Tags: php, wordpress

When I call get_post_custom in a loop, it works properly. But it prints 38 on my screen. Is it a wp bug or what? How can I fix it?

More Info:
It happens when I call get_post_meta as well. I am using custom field template plugin.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'attendeeaddress',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'MEETING_ID',
                'value' => $meeting_id,
                'meta_compare' => '='
            )
        )
    );
    $wpquery = new WP_Query($args);
    $addresses = array();
    while ( $wpquery->have_posts() ) : $wpquery->the_post();
        $custom_val = get_post_custom(the_ID());
        $addresses[] = array(
            "address" => $custom_val["MEETING_ADDRESS"][0],
            "meeting_id" => $meeting_id,
            "lat" => $custom_val["MEETING_LAT"][0],
            "lon" => $custom_val["MEETING_LON"][0],
            "name" => $custom_val["NAME"][0]
        );
    endwhile;

    return $addresses;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because **the_ID();** actually "echoes" the value.

To just collect the value, use **get_the_ID()**;

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_ID
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_ID

- you have to use this in the loop only.